How to Show Stage Manager Windows via Keyboard Shortcut
I would like to open Stage Manager windows using a keyboard shortcut instead of moving my cursor to the left side of the screen, which takes too much time. Is it possible to achieve this by pressing specific keyboard buttons? For example, I would like to use a shortcut like Shift+1 to open the Stage Manager windows quickly.
Here's a screenshot illustrating the Stage Manager feature I'm referring to:


I downloaded BetterTouchTool and made this configuration, it solved this task.

Now, when I press ShiftCmd1 it opens Stage Manager.
